# Could the markdown help not also display the effect of the examples

Tags: feature-request, markdown, help-center

I would appreciate it if the [markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html) were to display the effect of all its examples.

Of course one can use cut-and-past-and-trial-and-error, but that is quite cumbersome by comparison, and I imagine this would be pretty simple to realise.
It could of course be made a little more fancy by making it optional whether to display the effects.